# ((basename($PHP_SELF) == FILENAME_DEFAULT

Tags: php

i want right box to be seen only index.php
code

```
if ($oscTemplate->hasBlocks('boxes_column_right')) {
?>
<div id="columnRight" class="grid_<?php echo $oscTemplate->getGridColumnWidth(); ?>">
<div><?php echo $oscTemplate->getBlocks('boxes_column_right'); ?></div> 
alternative with index page
if ($oscTemplate->hasBlocks('boxes_column_right')) && ((basename($PHP_SELF) == FILENAME_DEFAULT)) {
?>
<div id="columnRight" class="grid_<?php echo $oscTemplate->getGridColumnWidth(); ?>">
<div><?php echo $oscTemplate->getBlocks('boxes_column_right'); ?></div>
```

but it did not wo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$basename = str_replace(".php","",basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
if( $basename == "index" ) {
  //show right column
}
```

OR

```
$name = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if ($oscTemplate->hasBlocks('boxes_column_right')) && (($name == "index.php")) {
  //show right column
}
```

did you mean something like that

Answer (score 0):

I used this to do a similar task:

`if ($current_page = FILENAME_DEFAULT) {
    //Show
    }`